# Get data with ajax from php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this code,when i input invoice code it will get data from MySQL and fill the others text with Ajax. but my ajax don't get return from my controller, any body help me? where I'm wrong?

My controller in PHP to get data.

```
<?php 
  public function getDetail_transaction($invoice_id){
    $result = $this->db->get_where('tblTransaction',  array('payment_trx_id' => $invoice_id))->first_row();
    $data = json_encode($result);
    return $data;
  }
?>
```

My view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h3>Confirm Your Payment</h3>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <form name='ConfirmPayment' action="<?php echo base_url('Payment/ConfirmPayment');?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Invoice ID</label>   
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name='invoice_id' id='invoice_id' placeholder="Invoice ID" style='width:80%;'/>
                            <a type="submit" id='cek_invoice' class="btn cek_invoice">Cek</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nama Rekening Pembayar</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='user_account_name' id='user_account_name' placeholder="Nama Pembayar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bank Asal</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='provider_bank' id='provider_bank' placeholder="Nama Pembayar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bank Tujuan</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='payment_bank_user_name' id='payment_bank_user_name' placeholder="Bank Tujuan">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>No Transafer</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='no_transaction' id='no_transaction' placeholder="Jumlah di Transfer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Transfer Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='transfer_date' id='transfer_date' placeholder="Jumlah di Transfer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Deskripsi</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name='description' id='description' placeholder="Jumlah di Transfer"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Total Transfer</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='total_transfer' placeholder="No total_transfer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bukti Transaksi (optional)</label>
                        <input type="file" name="scan">
                      </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ajax Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cek_invoice").click(function(){
        data_invoice = $('#invoice_id').val();
        var url = "<?php echo base_url('Payment/getDetail_transaction/');?>"+'/'+data_invoice;
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                 $('#payment_bank_user_name').val(data.payment_bank_user_name);
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: use  echo  $data; instead of  return $data; in controller

Comment: the result {"TransactionID":"863","GuestID":"0","VehicleGroupID":"1","VehicleGroupName":"Kendaraan Penumpang"} but in ajax it doesnt return anything

Comment: `echo json_encode($result);` echo it, dont return it.

Comment: How i can, echo the result in my textbox?

Comment: after i echo json_encode($result); and then in my ajax, how i can put the data in my textbox?

Comment: @RezhaVelly: you have to firstly parse JSON data with `JSON.parse(data)` in your `success` callback like so: `var parsed = JSON.parse(data); $('#payment_bank_user_name').val(parsed.payment_bank_user_name);`

Comment: OT: I propose to use shortag for echo in HTML: `<?=` means `<?php echo`, just for brewity of your code. I assume you use PHP >= 5.4, this is enabled since PHP >= 5.3

Comment: Thx buddy, thx friends, thx all. The problem solved :D

Comment: @Vaclav Why i have to use short tag php? it's any plus point in short tag php?

Comment: @RezhaVelly: there are two plus points: + less typing + shorter code :) You don't have to use it, it's just my little advice.

Comment: @Vaclav thx budy for your advice :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should 'echo' result after encode it! see this:

```
<?php 
            public function getDetail_transaction($invoice_id){
                    $result = $this->db->get_where('tblTransaction',  array('payment_trx_id' => $invoice_id))->first_row();
                    $data = json_encode($result);
                    echo $data;   //echo data
            }
?>
```

in ajax you should parseJSON your data :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cek_invoice").click(function(){
    data_invoice = $('#invoice_id').val();
    var url = "<?php echo base_url('Payment/getDetail_transaction/');?>"+'/'+data_invoice;
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            var dun = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#payment_bank_user_name').val(dun.payment_bank_user_name);
        },
        failure: function() {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
}); });
```

Comment: thx, i know the problem why ajax don't get the data from php. but i have new problem, How i can, echo the result  from ajax to my textbox?

Comment: yes the problem solved thx, but i have new problem, how i can put the data from ajax to textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo $data;exit;
```

Instead of

```
return $data;
```

To display the data (after getting the response) -

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
$('#your_input_field').val(data.payment_bank_user_name);
```

Comment: thx, i know the problem why ajax don't get the data from php. but i have new problem, How i can, echo the result  from ajax to my textbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getDetail_transaction($invoice_id){
    $result = $this->db->get_where('tblTransaction', array('payment_trx_id' => $invoice_id))->first_row();    
    $data = json_encode($result);    
    echo $data;
}
```

and your javascript edit the below line

```
success: function(data) {    
  alert(data);    
  var obj = $.parseJSON(data);    
  $('#payment_bank_user_name').val(obj.payment_bank_user_name);    
},
```